# How to express a Double in Shape.SetFormula?

Tags: string, vb.net, integer, double

I am trying to input a Double value into a Shape.SetFormula command

for example the following is something which I recorded via the journaling function of NX:

```
moveObjectBuilder1.TransformMotion.Angle.SetFormula("12.5")
```

According to the microsoft website, the value inside the () can only be an Integer, and obviously, any value (no matter Integer or Double value) written in this form "xxx" can be executed.

As far as I understood, "" is a String, so I changed the code like the following :

```
Function value() As String
Return 25/2
End Function

Sub Main(ByVal As String)
.
.
.
moveObjectBuilder1.TransformMotion.Angle.SetFormula(value())
.
.
.
End Sub
```

However, there will be a syntax error if the code is written like this.

May I ask, how can I let the Shape.Formula() command read a Double value? Or how can I let the Function return a value which will be in this format "..."?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You specifically state that the value has to be an integer and then you wonder why passing a value that is not an integer doesn't work. Why is there a question? Maybe if you were to provide some relevant information, like what NX is, what this `Shape` class is, etc. None of your tags indicate anything outside of the basics yet there's obviously things going on here that you haven't bothered to explain. If you were to explain, maybe we could consult the relevant documentation for ourselves and see if there is anything that you have missed.

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at expressing myself. NX is a CAD software. There is a function in NX called journaling, it records all the things I have done. If I am to provide such long code it would kinda be a mess. Therefore I've shortened it like this.  `moveObjectBuilder1.TransformMotion.Angle.SetFormula("12.5")` means that I am moving an object by rotating it in 12.5 degrees. Also, this is where I checked for the information [link](https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/data_services/resources/nx/1899/nx_api/custom/en_US/nxopen_net/a03955.html#a308118abd2b8532f38085d1c603ac4ef)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with that application but, as far as I can tell, the parameter for that method is type `String` because it accepts a `String` containing a mathematical formula that will be parsed internally. In that case, something like this should work:

```vb
moveObjectBuilder1.TransformMotion.Angle.SetFormula("25 / 2")
```

and do exactly the same thing as this:

```vb
moveObjectBuilder1.TransformMotion.Angle.SetFormula("12.5")
```

If that's not working for you then please explain EXACTLY what happens when you do it.

Comment: Hello, yes `moveObjectBuilder1.TransformMotion.Angle.SetFormula("25 / 2")` will work, but this is actually not what I want. Because square root values are needed, and in VB square root of 2 is Math.Sqrt(2). And the code will be like this `moveObjectBuilder1.TransformMotion.Angle.SetFormula(" Math.Sqrt(2)")`
In this case, a syntax error will occur. And then the notification will state that only string values are allowed.

Comment: VB is irrelevant. You're not passing it VB code. You can only pass in what is understood by the engine that parses it and that is not VB. It may well support square roots but it 't look like that. Do some research to find out what syntax is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my own problem. It was actually quite stupid, I am just simply not an expert in programming. It only took me several more tries to get the solution to my problem.

`moveObjectBuilder1.TransformMotion.Angle.SetFormula("Sqrt(2)")`

This is the correct way to express "Rotate this object with the angle of square root of 2."

Okay now let's talk about the problem which I've encountered. What I want is, import a value via a function, and then process it. So, SetFormula only accepts `String`. Therefore I can do the following :

```
Function value() As Double
Return 25/2
End Function

Sub Main(ByVal arg() As String)
.
.
.
moveObjectBuilder1.TransformMotion.Angle.SetFormula(value().ToString)
.
.
.
End Sub
```